# Help on Workflow Time Trigger. How to send email alert everyday?

Tags: trigger, workflow, validation-rule, time-dependent-workflow

I would like to send an email alert everyday until the picklist is updated.

Scenario:
When my agent selects a picklist of "email" it will send "A" email alert to the email desired.

However, I would like the email to alert them everyday until the agent updates the picklist again.  I do have a date stamp called "Email Date" so I can track how long they take to update the record.

Can a workflow time trigger help me on this?  If so, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I made this workflow rule.

- Created a WF rule
- Criteria Status = Email & Email Date = Null
- Created a Time-Dependent Workflow Action of Email Alert 30 Days after Email Date

Will this work?  Will this email alert them everyday until the picklist status is changed?

Thanks again

Comment: I made this workflow rule.  Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create two workflow and one checkbox.

> WF criteria Create and everytime it is edited.

```
First WF will fire with condition **every time checkbox is false** and fire time trigger with email and set this checkbox to true.

Second WF will fire with condition **every time checkbox is true** and fire time trigger with email and set this checkbox to false.
```